# Где находится спецификация C++?

Tags: c++, спецификация

Подскажите, а где нормальная спецификация C++?

В Java находится легко - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html а для C++ есть нормальная?

Answer (score 0):

[ISO/IEC 14882 C++](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) - Стандарт языка